The column `_rescued_data` already exists during DELTA to DELTA streaming
I am working on a Spark Streaming job that reads data from a source Delta table and writes it to a target Delta table with SCD2 logic. However, I'm encountering an issue related to the "_rescued_data" column.
When streaming raw data into the first staging Delta table, Spark automatically adds a "_rescued_data" column to capture data that doesn't match the expected schema.
In the subsequent stream, attempting to write the data to the final Delta table (with SCD2 implementation) results in an error: "The column _rescued_data already exists."
I tried renaming "_rescued_data" to "_rescued_data_src" in the batch DataFrame (batch_df). However, this leads to join issues between batch_df and the target Delta table (sink_df) due to the column name mismatch.
I'm looking for guidance on how to handle the "_rescued_data" column while performing streaming with SCD2 logic in Delta tables. Ideally, I want to avoid the existing column error and ensure the data is processed correctly for SCD2 implementation.
Error:
[COLUMN_ALREADY_EXISTS] The column _rescued_data already exists. Consider to choose another name or rename the existing column. SQLSTATE: 42711

Are you using Azure databricks?

@DileepRajNarayanThumula Yes

Do the merging on the delta table as mentioned in this
documentation.
Here, either you set the column values or update all of the column.
Below is the sample code in pyspark.

Targetdf.alias('target') \
  .merge(
    batchdf.alias('updates'),
    'target.id = updates.id'
  ) \
  .whenMatchedUpdate(set =
    {
      "id": "updates.id",
      "firstName": "updates.firstName",
      "middleName": "updates.middleName",
      "lastName": "updates.lastName",
      "_rescued_data":"updates._rescued_data"
    }
  ) \
  .whenNotMatchedInsert(values =
    {
      "id": "updates.id",
      "firstName": "updates.firstName",
      "middleName": "updates.middleName",
      "lastName": "updates.lastName"
    }
  ) \
  .execute()

or update all column values.
(targetDF
  .merge(sourceDF, "source.key = target.key")
  .whenMatchedUpdateAll()
  .whenNotMatchedInsertAll()
  .execute()
)

Refer above provided documentation for more operations with conditions while merging the data.
I have tried reading the files as CSV using the following code:
df = (spark.readStream
        .format("cloudFiles")
        .option("cloudFiles.format", "csv")
        .schema(schema)  # Apply the dynamic schema
        .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", f"{sink_path}/schema")
        .option("sep", "\t")  # Tab-delimited
        .option("header", "true")  # First row is a header
        .option("encoding", "UTF-8")
        .option("cloudFiles.validateOptions", "false")  # Avoid strict validation
        .load(source_path)
        .withColumn("sourcefile", F.col("_metadata.file_path")) 
        .withColumn("load_timestamp", F.to_timestamp(F.regexp_extract(F.col("sourcefile"), "([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})", 1), 'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss')))
display(df)

When I run this, I don’t see any records in the output, just the Delta table with headers (provided via the schema).
It also seems that schema inference doesn’t work with .text files. Is this expected behavior, or am I missing something in my configuration?
